# Databind to a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a really hard time wrapping my head around the use of datatables. There for i been trying to use them more active, now this is where my issue surface.

This code returns no errors but no data is bound to the repeater:

Page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterBrand" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p><%# Eval("products_name")%></p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Codebehind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (Request.QueryString["brand"] != null && !IsPostBack)
    {

        var Brand = (Request.QueryString["brand"]);

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table_Products WHERE products_brand = @Pr_brand", conn);
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pr_brand", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Brand;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows && reader.Read())
        {
            dt.Load(reader);
            RepeaterBrand.DataSource = dt;
            RepeaterBrand.DataBind();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I'm quite new to C# so i might need some visual aid to get this.

Thank you in advance.

I hope this might help anyone this is what i ended up with after JaydipJ showed me the syntax.

```
        if (Request.QueryString["brand"] != null && !IsPostBack)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        var Brand = (Request.QueryString["brand"]);
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table_Products WHERE products_brand = @Pr_brand";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pr_brand", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Brand;

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        RepeaterBrand.DataSource = dt;
        RepeaterBrand.DataBind();
```

Comment: you have a debugger. please try and use it.

Comment: You have an extra `"` in Eval you should remove it `<p><%# Eval("products_name")%></p>`

Comment: Yeah i have removed that, yet its not the cause and i been using the de-bugger. it informs me that everything is running smooth. all values are collected and the datatable i filled (It's not null) yet the repeater do not act like theres any data to show.

Comment: how many rows ware fetch from db?

Comment: JaydipJ your right the reader only returns that it has rows but the count remain 0. Yet i can tell that the Querystring is added to the SqlCommand. so i can't figure out why it's not grabing the data.

Comment: @JaydipJ Any idea where i might have made my mistake cause I'm getting blind looking.

Comment: @JaydipJ Just what i needed to see, i made a edit with the code your help lead to it works now. thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't read data from SQLDataReader. use it as it is to fill DataTable

```
if (reader.HasRows )
{
   dt.Load(reader);
   RepeaterBrand.DataSource = dt;
   RepeaterBrand.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is what i needed to see, that was the visual aid i was looking for thank you thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code It's Working.

```
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Mst_Emp_Login.Emp_Uname from Mst_Emp_Login", con);
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adp.Fill(ds);
                Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
                ds.Dispose();adp.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                con.Close();con.Dispose();
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                throw err;
            }
```